# Are HOST_CACHED_BIT and HOST_COHERENT_BIT contradicting each other?

Tags: vulkan

There are two types of memory in Vulkan buzzling me:

> - `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT` bit indicates that the host cache
>     management commands `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` and
>     `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges` are not needed to flush host writes to
>     the device or make device writes visible to the host, respectively.
> - `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT` bit indicates that memory allocated
>     with this type is cached on the host. Host memory accesses to uncached
>     memory are slower than to cached memory, however uncached memory is
>     always host coherent.

From what I understand is that modification of memory of type COHERENT is seen immediately by both the host and the device, and modifications to memory of type CACHED may not be seen immediately by the host and/or the device, i.e. invalidating/flushing the memory is needed to invalidate the cache.

I have seen some implementations combine both flags, and it is valid combinations according to the [10.2. Device Memory](http://vulkan-spec-chunked.ahcox.com/ch10s02.html) section in the documentation. Isn't there a contradictory (cached and coherent)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cached/coherent memory effectively means that the GPU can see the CPU's caches. This often happens on architectures where the GPU and the CPU are sitting on the same chip. The GPU is effectively just another core on the CPU's die, with access to the CPU's core.

But it can happen on other architectures as well. [Some standalone GPUs](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=1526#memory) [offer cached/coherent memory](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=339#memory). Indeed, most of them don't offer cached memory without coherency. From an architectural standpoint, it represents some way for the GPU to access data through at least part of the CPU cache.

The key thing about cached/coherent memory you should remember is this: if there is an alternative memory type for that memory pool, then the alternative is probably *faster* for the device to access. Also, if alternatives exist, it is entirely possible that the device may not be able to have images or buffers of certain types/formats stored in such memory types. So unless you really need cached memory access from the CPU, or the device offers no alternative, it's best to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

There are cache schemes that monitor write accesses to RAM over the memory bus to invalidate the Host's cache when the memory is written to.

This allows the best of both worlds, cached coherent accesses but at the cost of a more complex architecture.